# how do I add captcha from a website to an app

Tags: android, captcha

I am trying t build an app that lets you search your train reservation details, the website has a Captcha to it, I need help with adding that captcha to the app.

Basically I'm trying to turn this page into an app: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

As I can see what you want is this part

```
<img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=&lt;?php echo rand(); ?&gt;" id="captchaimg">
```

now you have the Id of the element, use Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html").get();
Elements imgCaptcha= doc.select("#captchaimg");
String imgSrc=imgCaptcha.attr("src");
Log.d(Tag,"image source = "+imgSrc);
```

now create a stream and download it from imgSrc